# Can I delete my fork before the pull request gets accepted?

Tags: git, github, pull

I made a fork of a project on github, did a small correction and submitted a pull request. However, from every pull request “in line”, I can see that this developer will take a long time before reviewing mine. The thing is I don’t want the repository — I just forked it to solve that issue (that the developer itself had in the TODO).

My question is: if I delete the repository from my account, will the developer still be able to accept the pull request? It’s a change of just a few lines.

Comment: This is why GitLab's protected branche workflow is so cool: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/f22c709539d06be6fa76f148dedffdef1170936c/doc/workflow/authorization_for_merge_requests.md

Comment: This no longer seems to be true, when the pull request was marked as "closed" because the fork was deleted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. From [Gitub’s page on checking pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally):

> If a fork was deleted, the pull request can still be merged.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, all pull requests are available in the destination repository, even if the fork is deleted before it's merged.  The Git tree can be found at the refspec `pull/###/head`, where `###` is the pull request number.  The original project's owner can merge using the GitHub web interface or on the command line by downloading the branch:

```
git fetch origin pull/###/head:pullrequest
git merge pullrequest
```

Comment: Great answer. Short and easily understandable. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user137369: Great, but wrong.

Comment: @firegurafiku I know, that’s why it isn’t the accepted answer.

Comment: Hmm, yep, this seems to have changed since I posted it (or I was originally incorrect).  I'll edit to reflect the new info.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted a fork, and both the open issue and the relative pull request are still there, so I think it can be done.

Comment: The pull request is there, but it shows "Unknown branch" for me.

Comment: But the diff is still there, so the original branch being unknown doesn't really matter.